# Running a macro from the command line on a file that exceeds excels row/column limit

Tags: vba, csv, excel

I have been using a useful VB script that goes through a spreadsheet row by row, checks for duplicate cells in that row, deletes all the duplicates and shuffles all the cells along so there are no blanks.

It looks like this:

```
Sub StripRowDupes()
  Do Until ActiveCell = ""
     Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.End(xlToRight)).Select
     For Each Cell In Selection
        If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Selection, Cell) > 1 Then
           Cell.ClearContents
        Else
        End If
      Next Cell
      On Error Resume Next
      Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
      ActiveCell.Range("A2").Select
   Loop
End Sub
```

However, I now need to perform the same operation, only on a CSV file that has 48,051 columns and therefore wont load in excel due to its 16,000 column limit.

Can I run the script from the command line on the file?

How could I go about doing this?

Comment: How complex is the CSV - does it have quoted values, and do any of those values contain commas?  That determines how tricky it would be to parse each line using code instead of opening in Excel...

Answer (score 1):

You could load chunks of the .csv at a time, putting a prefix or suffix at the end of each import. Run VBA code on each chunk, then add back together.

Unfortunately the Workbooks.OpenText method supports importing text starting at a particular row, not a particular column, so you'd need to break up the .csv file into manageable chunks outside of excel, before running VBA code.